# adjusting font Size of Text for different screen sizes in jetpack compose

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

[image]

[image]

```
  Column(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .background(Color.White),
    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
) {
    Box(modifier = Modifier
        .size(200.dp, 200.dp)
        .clip(RoundedCornerShape(20.dp))
        .background(Color.Black)
        .clip(RoundedCornerShape(20.dp))
        .clickable {

            viewModel.setContent(
                name = anime.name,
                imageUrl = anime.imageUrl,
                totalEps = anime.totalEpisodes,
                aired = anime.aired,
                status = anime.status,
                rating = anime.rating,
                score = anime.score,
                scoreBy = anime.scoredBy,
                synopsis = anime.synopsis,
                studio = anime.studio,
                genres = anime.genres,
            )
            navController.navigate("animeInfoScreen")
        }){
        AsyncImage( contentScale = ContentScale.FillBounds
            ,modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()

               , model = ImageRequest.Builder(LocalContext.current)
                .data(anime.imageUrl)
                .build()
            , contentDescription = null,

            )
    }
    Text(text = if(anime.name.length>25){
        anime.name.substring(0,22)+"..."
    }else{
        anime.name
    })
```

> I am working on a project using Jetpack Compose, where I have a vertical grid displaying text. On smaller screen sizes, the text is rendered too large, causing it to overflow and not fit into one line within the grid box. I want to dynamically adjust the font size of the text to ensure it fits into the box properly, regardless of the screen size.

Comment: so first thing to do is check documentation for Text composable because clearly you don't know anything about it, for exemple instead of `anime.name.substring(0,22)+"..."`
you can use `overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis` and then specify max lines to 1 or something. over all check the documentation and if it doesn't help check for AutoResizeText compose in StackOverFlow it might help